# Providing AJAX With Rails-Generated URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Can I provide AJAX with a Rails URL/path?

For example, what I need is `url: articles/1/comments/1`.
Since I'm experiencing difficulties for some time now making AJAX execute this URL, I wonder if there's a way to use the Rails route I'm familiar with `[comment.article, comment]`.

Note:

I'm loading a DIV using AJAX:

```
#welcome/index.haml
- @articles.each do |article|
   = article.title
   - article.comments.each do |comment|
     %comment-content{ :id => "comment-#{ comment.id } %>", :class => "comment-content", "data-comment-id" => comment.id }
```

AJAX:

```
  var loadComment = function() {
  return $('.comment-content').each(function() {
    var comment_id = $(this).data('comment-id');
    return $.ajax({
      url: "" ,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'script',
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Why not adding `:remote => true` to the link?

Comment: The link will be modified by `jquery_ujs` and become automatically a ajax request. Check you routes and logs to see the result.

Comment: On top of your controller `respond_to :html, :js`

Comment: I've no idea if you understand the topic the right way. Do you know http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: If it's a submit button then mark the form with `:remote => true`.

Comment: It's a DIV. *Neither* a button nor a `link_to`.

Answer (score 0):

Rails provide data-remote attribute in form. It works like AJAX and it uses url as you added in form

you can use it like below:

```
<%= form_for([comment.article, comment], remote: true) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like

```
<%= form_for([comment.article, comment], remote: true) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

if you are using form_for or if you want to send ajax like:

```
$.ajax({

})
```

then you can use

```
$.ajax({
 url : "<%= url_for article_comment_path(article, comment)%>"

})
```

Comment: `<%= article_comment_path(article, comment)%>` does not work, please see me note above.